# How to set per-sub-project properties from a Gradle command line?

Tags: gradle

I have the following:

```
// File: build.gradle
subprojects {
    test {
        final testRatioOfWaitTimeToComputeTime = System.getProperty('test.ratio-of-wait-time-to-compute-time', '1') as int
        final testMaxParallelForks = (System.getProperty('test.max-parallel-forks') as Integer) ?: numberOfForks(testRatioOfWaitTimeToComputeTime)

        maxParallelForks testMaxParallelForks
    }
}
```

How would I:

- Specify a default for `test.ratio-of-wait-time-to-compute-time` and `test.max-parallel-forks` for **one** specific sub-project?
- Specify a command-line override for `test.ratio-of-wait-time-to-compute-time` and `test.max-parallel-forks` for **one** specific sub-project?

I've tried various combinations of `-P` and `-D` with both with and without prefixing the property with the sub-project name (eg `:sub-project:test.ratio-of-wait-time-to-compute-time`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System properties are JVM-wide, and therefore you can't set a system property for a specific subproject. You'll have to use separate system properties (e.g. named after the subprojects). Same for project properties.

PS: I don't understand/question the usefulness though.

Comment: The amount of parallelization of tests depends upon how CPU/IO intensive they are. Different sub-projects have different optimal parallelization settings.

Comment: But why do you need this to be configurable from the command line?

Comment: Because the defaults don't work well on some engineer's machines. I suppose they could set it in their user `.gradle` files, but allowing command-line settings allows for one-time configurations.